# C# get string from html page

Tags: c#, html, string

I have got all html text and convert it to string. It has format like in browser
("

.
.
.")

How I can get, for example, 145th string from this string?

Comment: Can you please expand `(" . . .")` and show a sample in your post. How does it look like? Without a sample it is hard to conceive as to what does 145th string really mean.

Comment: You can use http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex to easily parse html and extract data using xpath similar syntax